# iOS UITextView Always scroll to bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have this scenario: when I click on a UITextView, it will either expand or shrink. But every time the UITextView shrinks, the content scroll down to the bottom.

I've tried

```
[textView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES];
textView.scrollsToTop = YES;
```

But none of them works.

Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Here is the code:

```
- (IBAction)tapText:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"tap text view");
    [self addBoundsSpringAnimationToView:self.movieTextView];
}

- (void) addBoundsSpringAnimationToView:(UITextView *)textView {
    POPSpringAnimation *anim = [POPSpringAnimation animationWithPropertyNamed:kPOPLayerBounds];
    if (expand) {
        NSLog(@"expand");
        self.bgUIImageView.hidden = YES;
        self.blurredImageView.hidden = NO;
        anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 0.0f, 320.0f, 807.0f)];
        anim.springBounciness = 18;
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Shrink");
        self.bgUIImageView.hidden = NO;
        self.blurredImageView.hidden = YES;
        anim.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(0, 355.0f, 320.0f, 225.0f)];
    }
    expand = !expand;
    anim.springSpeed = 10;
    [textView pop_addAnimation:anim forKey:@"popBounds"];
}
```

Is it related to the Facebook Pop animation?

Thanks!

Comment: I think your "if-else" condition is not working correctly according to expand(bool) value, or expand is being set yes from somewhere, so please debug it again.

Comment: If your if-else condition working then in ur shrink case you could add [textView setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:YES]; or [textview scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0,0,1,1) animated:YES]; instead of it being at other place.

Comment: place setting your content offset at the end of the animation (does it have some sort of a callback function? there would be the best place to put it)

Comment: re: "Is it related to the Facebook Pop animation?" have you tried using a UIAnimation or even no animation?

Comment: @Arvind "if-else" condition is working. And expand is set only here.

Comment: @walle84 hmmm, I tried add both to shrink case and taxText function. But none works.

Comment: @MihaiAndreiRustiuc I tried add both to shrink case and taxText function. But none works.

Comment: @RogerNolan I'm guessing it's related to Pop animation.

Comment: Err. take it out then :-)